# PowerShell Q: Why this foreach-object change the value on both variables ? I want to change only to one ( $b )

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, script

As you see in this image or code, the foreach-object cmdlet change the value in both variables, but I want only change it on the second one, $b.

[image: IMG:]

It's a extract of the terminal itself:

```
PS C:\> $a    
PS C:\> $b    
PS C:\> $a = @{ Name = "Jhon" }    
PS C:\> $a

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name                           Jhon


PS C:\> $b = $a    
PS C:\> $b

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name                           Jhon

PS C:\> $b | ForEach-Object { $_.Name = "Richard" }    
PS C:\> $b

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name                           Richard


PS C:\> $a

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name                           Richard


PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.492
```

Has the "$b = $a" something in the middle ?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: take a look at what "by reference" and "by value" mean. you did NOT copy from the 1st to the 2nd ... you created a 2nd reference to the **_same object_**. [*grin*]